# After Update, All Active Directory Clients / Server have Black Screen

Tags: active-directory, rdp

I have the following problem. The latest updates have been installed since yesterday (28.06.2020). I have the problem with 2 systems that I can no longer connect to them.
This affects RDP, as well as the connection from Hyper-V Manager or Teamviewer.
A connection no longer works. The picture remains black.

So far, I can tell from the Powershell that all services are running, and the event log also reports no problems.

Unfortunately, these are the only ways I can still connect.

What is unusual is that 3-4 client computers have had the same problem since the update. However, these had not received an update yesterday.

During my research, I came up with the following solutions for RDP Black Screen
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/e29c1c20-5389-4ef8-a177-2b8d625d55fd/server-2019-rdp-session-black-screen?forum=winserverTS

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-winprotlp/e168a474-7de2-421c-b460-91adf87692a3?redirectedfrom=MSDN

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-1903-may-update-black-screen-with/23c8a740-0c79-4042-851e-9d98d0efb539?auth=1

Adding the corresponding settings in the registry and similar things that helped back then did not help here.
If I try to uninstall the updates, I get Powershell UnauthorizedExceptions,

I tried to uninstall using the following script

```
$ KBs = Get-WUHistory -Last 7 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty kb
Foreach ($ KB to $ KBs) {
Uninstall-WindowsUpdate -KBArticleID $ KB
}
```

In desperation I had meanwhile tried to reinstall the affected RDP server. (As a secondary machine) everything works so far, updates can be installed, and the phenomenon does not repeat itself for the time being. However, as soon as I add the computer to the AD. I get the server started up exactly 1 time. However, can then no longer call the start / search, this then no longer reacts. The next time you restart, you will only see the black screen and nothing will happen.

Hence the suspicion that it must have something to do with the update + of the domain.

Slowly I no longer know why the whole problem arises. Did someone already have that? Or does anyone have any idea what that could be?

In the meantime a 2 independent IT specialist had also looked at it, and only came up with the same solutions that I had already found.

I'm slowly getting desperate.

best regards

Xoroles

P.S. Infrastructure

Windows 2019 server
Hyper-V virtualization
Hyper-V host is not in the domain,
one DC is a guest operating system, 2 DC is another physical location.

So far, the client problems have only occurred at the location with the virtual machine. Only tomorrow can I say whether the problem also occurs at the other location, since everyone was in the home office today.

Comment: Did you install drivers or just the OS updates?

Comment: Probably something weird in a GPO. Create a new OU, copy all the GPO links from the production OU, confirm that the problem is still present and remove GPO links one by one until the problem is gone, then, you'll be able to find the offending setting

Comment: Yes I Have only installed OS Updates

Comment: Hello Swisstone, i think, this is the Problem! I Have Deactivate all Links, and now the Systems Boot normally. 
I Think it is the Default Domain Policy with the Problem